# MY METAMASK GOT HACKED

Tags: metamask

3 hours ago, somebody stole most of my coins out of Metamask. For 2000 dollars!!
For the second time! In August for the first time. But then I left my Metamask unlocked so I thought this was the reason.
Now again, while I always unlock, they stole it again.
And you can see perfectly on Etherscan to which address.
In my Metamask it's even my 'preferred address". How is this possible?

Comment: you should have stopped using the metamask wallet after the first hack

Comment: are you using the same account or laptop`?

Answer (score 2):

Someone must somehow have stolen your private key (your secret phrase). You are probably saving your private key somewhere unsafe that someone saw it (on your phone or your laptop where it is obvious)

Most probably the first time you left it unlocked, a person exported your private key. From then he/she has access to your account even when you don't have it unlocked on your laptop. he/she can easily import your private key to his Metamask and open your account freely and transfer to any account whenever he/she wants to.

You must change your private key. The only way to do this is to make another account and transfer your Eth from the old account to the new one to prevent further theft.

Also, make sure your new private key (your phrase) is safe and no one can access or guess its place.

Comment: is he a victim of a backdoor hacker, or remote eavesdropper? not sure what you mean by "unlocked, exported private key"

Comment: @user610620 probably eavesdrop. someone close to him may have had his password. (this may happen in his workplace, done by a coworker or a roommate). In this case, the thief can go to account details and export the private key using his password. then import it later on his own computer.

Comment: how could this be done to him  by a remote backdoor eavesdropper on a laptop half-way across the world?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. by eavesdropping I meant someone looking at his password while he's typing it or something like that. Looking through his laptop to find the password. Or maybe the password was something obvious and easy to guess if you know the person's favorite things in life.

Comment: I know that's what you meant. that's why i'm asking about the other case

Comment: your question is related to information security. you can find the full detailed answer on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/). There are several ways to eavesdrop or monitor someone's activity on a computer through another computer. But if you are aware enough, it won't happen.